How to Save Captured Image to USB with QtQuick 6.7?
I'm using Qt Quick and Boot2Qt RaspberryPi to make a simple GUI that connects to a USB webcam, shows the livestream and when the user clicks the capture button, it saves the capture to a USB flashdrive. The video streaming is working, but the capturing to flash drive is not. Nothing shows up on the flash drive, I have remoted into the Pi and created an empty text file so I don't think its a permission issue, and I have verified the path and name of the flashdrive. I'm trying to follow their QML Camera Example.
App.qml
import QtQuick 6.6
import "."

Window {
    width: homeScreen.width
    height: homeScreen.height

    visible: true
    title: "CCU_Proposal"

    HomeScreen {
        id: homeScreen
    }

    DeclarativeCamera {
        id: declarativeCamera
    }

    PhotoCaptureControls {
        id: photoCaptureControls
        captureSession: declarativeCamera.captureSession
        imageCapture: declarativeCamera.imageCapture
    }

DeclarativeCamera.qml
import QtQuick
import QtMultimedia

Rectangle {
    id : cameraUI

    color: "black"
    state: "PhotoCapture"

    property string platformScreen: ""
    property CaptureSession captureSession: captureSessionInternal
    property ImageCapture imageCapture: imageCaptureInternal

    states: [
        State {
            name: "PhotoCapture"
            StateChangeScript {
                script: {
                    camera.start()
                }
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "PhotoPreview"
        },
        State {
            name: "VideoCapture"
            StateChangeScript {
                script: {
                    camera.start()
                }
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "VideoPreview"
            StateChangeScript {
                script: {
                    camera.stop()
                }
            }
        }
    ]

    CaptureSession {
        id: captureSessionInternal
        camera: Camera {
            id: camera
        }
        imageCapture: ImageCapture {
            id: imageCaptureInternal

            onImageSaved: {
                console.log("Image saved successfully to: " + fileName);
            }

            onErrorOccurred: {
                console.error("Capture error: " + errorString);
            }
        }

        recorder: MediaRecorder {
            id: recorder
//             resolution: "640x480"
//             frameRate: 30
        }
        videoOutput: viewfinder
    }

    PhotoPreview {
        id : photoPreview
        anchors.fill : parent
        onClosed: cameraUI.state = "PhotoCapture"
        visible: (cameraUI.state === "PhotoPreview")
        focus: visible
        source: imageCapture.preview
    }

    VideoPreview {
        id : videoPreview
        anchors.fill : parent
        onClosed: cameraUI.state = "VideoCapture"
        visible: (cameraUI.state === "VideoPreview")
        focus: visible

        //don't load recorded video if preview is invisible
        source: visible ? recorder.actualLocation : ""
    }

    VideoOutput {
        id: viewfinder
        visible: ((cameraUI.state === "PhotoCapture") || (cameraUI.state === "VideoCapture"))
        anchors.fill: parent
        //        autoOrientation: true
    }

    PhotoCaptureControls {
        id: stillControls
        anchors.fill: parent
        captureSession: captureSessionInternal
        imageCapture: imageCaptureInternal
        visible: (cameraUI.state === "PhotoCapture")
        onPreviewSelected: cameraUI.state = "PhotoPreview"
        onVideoModeSelected: cameraUI.state = "VideoCapture"
        previewAvailable: imageCapture.preview.length !== 0
    }

    VideoCaptureControls {
        id: videoControls
        anchors.fill: parent
        captureSession: captureSessionInternal
        visible: (cameraUI.state === "VideoCapture")
        onPreviewSelected: cameraUI.state = "VideoPreview"
        onPhotoModeSelected: cameraUI.state = "PhotoCapture"
    }
}

PhotoCaptureControls.qml
import QtQuick
import QtMultimedia
import QtQuick.Layouts

FocusScope {
    id : captureControls
    property CaptureSession captureSession
    property ImageCapture imageCapture

    property bool previewAvailable : false

    signal previewSelected
    signal videoModeSelected

    // ZoomControl {
    //     id: zoomControl

    //     currentZoom: captureControls.captureSession.camera.zoomFactor
    //     maximumZoom: captureControls.captureSession.camera.maximumZoomFactor
    //     onZoomTo: (target) => captureControls.captureSession.camera.zoomFactor = target
    // }

    function handleCaptureButtonClick() {
        console.log("Capture button clicked");

        var usbPath = "/run/media/USBFLASHDRIVE-sda1";
        var timestamp = new Date().toISOString().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
        var fullPath = usbPath + "/" + timestamp + ".jpg";
        console.log("Full path for captured image: " + fullPath);

        // Directly proceed if already ready
        if (captureSession.imageCapture.readyForCapture) {
            captureImage(fullPath);
        } else {
            // Connect to the readyForCaptureChanged signal to wait for readiness
            captureSession.imageCapture.readyForCaptureChanged.connect(function() {
                if (captureSession.imageCapture.readyForCapture) {
                    captureImage(fullPath);
                    // Disconnect the signal to avoid multiple connections
                    captureSession.imageCapture.readyForCaptureChanged.disconnect(arguments.callee);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function captureImage(fullPath) {
        try {
            captureSession.imageCapture.captureToFile(fullPath);
            console.log("Capture to file initiated...");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Failed to capture to file: ", error);
        }
    }

When I click the capture button, I get this output:
16:47:20: Starting /usr/bin/appcontroller /usr/bin/redacted on Pi 4...
"DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" "unix:path=/run/user/0/dbus_session_socket"
"QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX" "1"
"QT_IM_MODULE" "qtvirtualkeyboard"
"QT_QPA_EGLFS_FORCE888" "1"
"QT_QPA_EGLFS_KMS_ATOMIC" "0"
"QT_QPA_PLATFORM" "eglfs"
"QT_WAYLAND_HARDWARE_INTEGRATION" "linux-dmabuf-unstable-v1"
"SQUISH_PREFIX" "/opt/squish"
"WAYLAND_DISPLAY" "/run/wayland-0"
"XDG_RUNTIME_DIR" "/run/user/0"
"/usr/bin/CCU_ProposalApp" QList()
qml: Capture button clicked
qml: Full path for captured image: /run/media/USBFLASHDRIVE-sda1/20240403204743165.jpg
qml: Capture to file initiated...
I'm thinking it might be a syntax/class issue since the onImageSaved codeblock is not firing.
